# OneMenu & 2 ajax inside won't work

Tags: ajax, primefaces, dropdown, selectonemenu

I'm facing a huge problem since 2 weeks.

I tested 2 ajax method one by one and they work. But when I want to have both in a oneMenu, the dropdown supposed to update the third oneMenu of the page does'nt work.

```
<h:body>
        <h:form>

            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
            <p:outputLabel value="Sélectionner une section " for="sectionBox"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="sectionBox" 
                             value="#{evaluationViewController.currentSection}"
                             converter="sectionConverter"
                             var="c"
                             filter="true"
                             filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                             effect="fade"
                             >
                <p:ajax listener="#{evaluationViewController.onSectionSelected}" update="ue,ueO,growl"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez uen section" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{evaluationViewController.currentSections}"
                               var="currentSection"
                               itemLabel="#{currentSection.name}"
                               itemValue="#{currentSection}"
                               />
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{c.name}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Sélectionner une UE " for="ue"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="ue"
                             value="#{evaluationViewController.ue}"
                             converter="ueConverter"
                             var="u"
                             filter="true"
                             filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                             >
                <p:ajax listener="#{evaluationViewController.onUeSelected}" update="ueO,growl"/>
                <p:ajax event="change" update="capacities" listener="#{evaluationViewController.listenerCapacitiesUpdate}"/>
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez une UE" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{evaluationViewController.ues}"
                               var="ues"
                               itemLabel="#{ues.name}"
                               itemValue="#{ues}"
                               />

                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{u.name}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Sélectionner l'UE enseignée" for="ueO"/>
            <p:selectOneMenu id="ueO"
                             value="#{evaluationViewController.organizedUe}"
                             converter="organizedUeConverter"
                             var="o"
                             filter="true"
                             filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                             >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez une année" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems 
                    value="#{evaluationViewController.organizedUes}"
                    var="organizedUes"
                    itemLabel="#{organizedUes.name}"
                    itemValue="#{organizedUes}"
                    />
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.name}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.level.name}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:separator/>
            <p:separator/>

            <p:dataTable id="capacities"
                         var="cap"
                         value="#{evaluationViewController.capacities}"
                         editable="true"
                         editMode="cell"
                         widgetVar="cellCap"
                         >

                <f:facet name ="header">
                    Capacitées
                </f:facet>

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" 
                        listener="#{evaluationViewController.onCellEdit}" 
                        update="@this"/>

                <p:column headerText="Dénomination">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{cap.name}"/></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{cap.name}" style="width: 30%" label="Dénomination"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Description">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{cap.description}"/></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><h:inputText value="#{cap.description}" style="width: 90%" label="Description"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Réussite obligatoire">
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cap.isThresholdOfSuccess}" style="alignment-adjust: central"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:separator/>               

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

I followed the primefaces demo as well for the bean :

```
public class EvaluationViewController implements Serializable {
@EJB
private SectionFacade ejbSectionFacade;
private List<Section> currentSections;
private Section currentSection;

@EJB
private UeFacade ejbUeFacade;
private List<Ue> ues;
private Ue ue;

@EJB
private OrganizedUeFacade ejbOrganizedUeFacade;
private List<OrganizedUe> organizedUes;
private OrganizedUe organizedUe;

@EJB
private CapacityFacade ejbCapacity;
private List<Capacity> capacities;
private Capacity capacity;
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    currentSections = ejbSectionFacade.findAll();
    ues = new ArrayList<>();
    organizedUes = new ArrayList<>();
    capacities = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void onSectionSelected() {
    if (currentSection != null && !currentSection.getName().equals("")) {
        ues = ejbUeFacade.findBySection(currentSection);
        ue = null;
        capacity = null;
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Sélection", currentSection.getName());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    } else {
        ues = null;
    }
}

public void onUeSelected() {
    if ((currentSection != null && !currentSection.getName().equals(""))
            && (ue != null && !ue.getName().equals(""))) {
        organizedUes = ejbOrganizedUeFacade.findByUe(ue);
        capacities = ejbCapacity.findByUe(ue);
        capacity = null;
        FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("Sélection de l'UE : ", ue.getName());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, facesMessage);
    } else {
        organizedUes = null;
    }
}

public void listenerCapacitiesUpdate() {
    capacities = ejbCapacity.findByUe(ue);
}
```

The DataTable is updated and rendered but not the last oneMenu. I really don't get it. I would be very gratefull for the answer.

Comment: Please create an [mcve] and be specific about which component does not update others. And of the two ajax tags, one does not have an event. So if the default by accident is 'change', the second one overrides the other

Comment: Thanks !!! It works so great !!!

Comment: Changing or rather adding an explicit and different event in the first `p:ajax`? Let me create an answer then. I don't think there is a duplicate of this Q/A yet

Comment: Yeah ok because I m not so familiar with stackoverflow.

Comment: You can 'accept' good answers and if it was really helpful, you can even upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things at hand here:

- If you do not provide an explict event, then a default one is taken
- You cannot add two ajax tags to the same component listening to the same event

So if in this case the default ajax event of the `p:selectOneMenu` is `change`, only the second one will be processed. **Adding an explicit event other than `change` to the first ajax handler will make it work**

Off-topic but important things you should normally do debugging issues like this:

- Find the differences between the two and see and try to make them as identical as possible
- See if the order plays a role by switching them
- See if using a different component makes it work